# Threshold for multiple columns flag in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
Id Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4
1   90    92    90    94
2   90    94    91    96
3   90    70    95    40
4   90    66    99    33
```

I have a table like the above (called `df`) how do I flag every row where Task1-Task4 are all over 90? I want to do this without individually checking the threshold for each task. So far I've only been able to do this by checking all 4 columns. What is more dynamic way of doing this in R using tidyverse syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the minimum of Tasks per row is larger or equal to 90.

```r
library(dplyr)


df <- read.table(text = 
                   "
Id Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4
1   90    92    90    94
2   90    94    91    96
3   90    70    95    40
4   90    66    99    33
", header = T)


df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(flag =min(across(starts_with('Task'))) >= 90)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      Id Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4 flag 
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl>
#> 1     1    90    92    90    94 TRUE 
#> 2     2    90    94    91    96 TRUE 
#> 3     3    90    70    95    40 FALSE
#> 4     4    90    66    99    33 FALSE
```

Comment: This wont work dynamically because it just checks the sums. What if one task is less than 90 and there are 10 columns, but the sum is over 900?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr >= 1.0.0`'s `rowwise()`. Note that in your example data no row has a value larger than 90 in all four columns.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = 
                   "
Id Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4
1   90    92    90    94
2   90    94    91    96
3   90    70    95    40
4   90    66    99    33
", header = T)


df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(flag = all(c_across(Task1:Task4) > 90))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      Id Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4 flag 
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl>
#> 1     1    90    92    90    94 FALSE
#> 2     2    90    94    91    96 FALSE
#> 3     3    90    70    95    40 FALSE
#> 4     4    90    66    99    33 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at basic R functionality. You can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
                   "
    Id Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4
    1   90    92    90    94
    2   90    94    91    96
    3   90    70    95    40
    4   90    66    99    33
    ", header = T)

# assuming strictly greater, threshold = 90
df$flag <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x, thres) all(x[-1] > thres),
                 thres=90)
```

You can provide a vector of thresholds in case it is different for each row (Id).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df$flag <- rowSums(df[-1] >90) == ncol(df[-1])
```

---

Or with `Reduce`

```
df$flag <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[-1], `>`, 90))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 1:4, Task1 = c(90L, 90L, 90L, 90L), Task2 = c(92L, 
94L, 70L, 66L), Task3 = c(90L, 91L, 95L, 99L), Task4 = c(94L, 
96L, 40L, 33L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```